# How to animate smooth animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

So I have been learning animations with JS,CSS,HTML and I was trying to learn how to animate a scroll similar to a [this](https://i.gyazo.com/bf66f1069fe628d0ba150633b65a4eea.mp4)

I have tried to use jQuery-SlotMachine though I am very lost on how the action is executed even with the JS code next to it. Could someone explain me how I can code this with the same API or another or Code it in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try CSS animations with a little javascript code to control your custom animation state.

I think my sample could help you.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/skorolchuk/pen/pKdpPZ)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $elements = $(".element");
  let $transitionList = $(".transition-list");

  let currentIndex = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    $transitionList.css(
      "transform",
      "translateY(" + currentIndex * -250 + "px)"
    );
    currentIndex++;
    if ($elements.length - 1 < currentIndex) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.border-container {
  border: 25px solid #dfe0a0ed;
  border-radius: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.transition-list {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px; 
  background-color: #fefefe;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 1);    
}

.element {
  background-color: #6f6f6f;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 188px;
  display: flex;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<div class="conainer center">
  <div class="border-container">
<div class="transition-list">
  <div class="element center"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></div>
  <div class="element center"><i class="fas fa-unlock"></i></div>
  <div class="element center"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
  <div class="element center"><i class="fas fa-american-sign-language-interpreting"></i></div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to do this with images , how would i do so

Comment: Just replace <i> tag with yours <img> tag. <div class="element"> is a container for icon, picture or video content. It should be worked in the same way.

In addition, you can replace my setInterval function with <button> click handlers.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** To begin, you must have a container:

```
<div id="theContainer" class="container">
</div>
```

**2.** Great, now let's put some images in it.

```
<div id="theContainer" class="container">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?random">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?random">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?random">
</div>
```

**3.** Now, let's add two buttons to move it:

```
<div id="theContainer" class="container">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=0">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=1">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=2">
</div>
<button id="prev" value="Previous">
<button id="next" value="Next">
```

**4.** Sweet! We got our HTML, now we just got to add our Javascript:

```js
// Set up previous button
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('#prev');

// Set up Next Button
const btnNext = document.querySelector('#next');

// Set up our container
const el = document.querySelector('#theContainer');

// Create new SlotMachine
const slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});

// Add Event Listeners or do things when we click it
btnPrev.addEventListener('click', () => slot.prev());
btnNext.addEventListener('click', () => slot.next());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css"></style>

<div id="theContainer" class="container" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=0"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=2"></div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>

<!-- Add script files -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
```

**5.** Notes:

- you must add a width & height to `#theContainer`. (`style="width: 100px; height: 100px"`)
- the images must be surrounded by a block element. (`<div><img /></div>`)

Comment: how could i do this with scroll? like I see you have a button listener so for a scroll listener would i tell it to run "() => slot.prev()" when it detects a scroll